# Can you set background color of a Three.js TextGeometry object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, colors, three.js

I have a basic THREE.js TextGeometry object in my scene:

```
const loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
const linkToFont ='link-to-font';
let textGeo;
const self = this;
loader.load(linkToFont, function (font) {
  textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry('Hello three.js!', {
    font,
    size: 0.3,
    height: 0.01,
  });
  textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
  const textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
  const textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo, textMaterial);
  textMesh.position.set(-100, 0, 0);
  textMesh.updateMatrixWorld();
  self.addToScene(textMesh);
});
```

This renders text in red on my scene. Is it possible to give the text in this area a "background color"? I.e. a rectangular solid color behind the text itself?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

1. If you want to cover the entire canvas in a single color, use [scene.background](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/scenes/Scene.background) to cover the whole canvas `scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x9900ff)`.
2. If you want to limit the area that the background color covers, just create a [plane](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=plane#api/en/geometries/PlaneGeometry) behind the text with the color that you want in the `MeshBasicMaterial`.